# Difference between 'accident' and 'coincidence'

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering about the usage of **accident**. In some behind the scenes material of 'Fast and the Furious' Vin Diesel made a joke. He is obviously a good driver, also in real life, so he said:

> It is no **accident** the name is Diesel.

Could you also use coincidence instead of accident and would it still have the same meaning?

Also, when do you use **accident** and when do you use **coincidence**?

Comment: What were the dictionary definitions that left you still uncertain about this?

Comment: I couldn't find anything about the proper usage. In many dictionaries there doesn't seem to be a difference between those two words (if they express that something unexpected happens), but my English teacher told me that coincidence is rather used than accident. However, Vin Diesel used it and that's why I was still uncertain, mostly about when to use accident and when coincidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually if a person's name happens to be particularly appropriate for him in some way we would say that it was a coincidence. A coincidence is usually two or more chance events which happen to turn out in the same way.

So if the bank manager's name is Mrs Cash this is probably a coincidence, assuming that she chose her profession and her husband separately. If a man and his  wife have the same birthday then we could say that is a coincidence. Out of all the days of the year it just so happens their birthdays are the same. However, a man and his wife having the same Wedding Anniversary is not a coincidence, as there are not two separate events which just so happened on the same day. It would not be possible for the husband to get married on one date and the wife on another. Their wedding was one single event.

An accident is something which happens without any deliberate intention. It usually involves a person doing something, but not always.

An accident can also be a coincidence. For example, two friends, Alice and Barbara, may happen to meet while shopping. If each of them could have gone shopping at any time and just by chance both went at the same time then we could say they met by accident or they met by coincidence. Both would be true.

Very often, but not always, the word accident has connotations of something bad happening. So Alice would be more likely to say she had met Barbara by chance, or by coincidence, rather than by accident. If however Alice had deliberately gone in the afternoon because she thought Barbara would go in the morning, and wished to avoid her, then accident would be  appropriate.

If two chance events are described as a coincidence they usually have some degree of similarity, either in nature or effect. Two people happening to have the same birthday or two people arriving at the same time, or a person's name matching his nature are coincidences.
If a slate falls off a roof at the exact moment a man is walking past, injuring the man, then this is an accident. It would not be usual to say that the fact the slate fell at the exact same moment the man was passing was a coincidence, because the two events, a man walking down a street and a slate falling off a roof,  are so different. However if another slate fell off another roof and injured another man at exactly the same time then that would be a coincidence.

If somebody had deliberately dislodged the slate with the intention of causing injury this would not be a coincidence or an accident.

In the case of Vin Diesel, when he said it was no accident that his name was Diesel he was speaking the truth. His birth name was not Diesel, it was Mark Sinclair Vincent. Diesel is a name  he chose to adopt, so in saying it is no accident that his name is Diesel he was referring to the fact that the name Diesel was a deliberate choice he made. Assuming he made the choice because of his interest in cars then it is not a coincidence either.     He was basically saying "this is why I call myself Diesel".

Comment: "To be a coincidence two chance events have to have a similar nature." I'm not sure I buy that; I think the distinction you're trying to make is more about causality. It's a coincidence that the slate happened to fall off just at the moment the guy was passing under (two independent events), but it was an accident that the man got hurt (cause and effect: the man got hurt, and the cause of that hurt doesn't involve deliberate intention).

Comment: To be more explicit, I'd say "coincidence" refers to two events regardless of their relationship (and how surprising it is they happened at the same time), and "accident" is about an event and its cause (and the fact this cause doesn't involve deliberate intention).

Comment: @davidlol: Nice and comprehensive answer, nicely explained. Helps a lot, thank you!

Comment: @RozennKeribin  I'm not sure.  If my friend tells me he had fish and chips for tea, I would not say 'that's a coincidence because I had bacon and eggs".  Would it be a coincidence if at the same time my sister was taking my nephew to the park I was painting the garage.    Wouldn't we only say there  was a coincidence if the events were related and similar and in a surprising way?    .

Comment: @davidlol You're right, "regardless of their relationship" was a bit strong; a coincidence involves a combination of events that is surprising, and so the events must be related in SOME way for that combination to be surprising to us. What I was trying to say is that this isn't a very restrictive constraint, it leaves tons of things the relationship could be, unlike "accident" which involves cause and effect. I also don't think it follows the events must have a similar nature, which is what you said in the part of your answer that I was replying to.

Comment: @RozennKeribin   Yes I see what you mean, I think. I've amended the first sentence of paragraph 6 to loosen the constraint and say the similarity could be in effect rather than nature. I'd appreciate your opinion.

Comment: @davidlol I really appreciate this conversation; I don't think what you've written matches what I've been saying though. I wasn't saying that coincidences are when events are similar in effect; I was suggesting that the difference between "coincidence" and "accident" isn't about the *similarity* of the events, but about the relationship of the events to one another: cause and effect for accidents, surprising juxtaposition for coincidences. Which doesn't require similarity in nature or effect; for example, I WOULD say "what a coincidence that the guy was passing by just as the slate fell off".

Comment: ... in that case the surprising juxtaposition wouldn't be because the nature or effect of the events are similar, but because their interaction caused such an unfortunate consequence (is that what you meant by "similar in their effect" maybe ?). And I could ALSO say "It was an accident that the guy got hit by a falling slate"; in this case I wouldn't be commenting on the surprising juxtaposition, but I would be claiming that the cause of the whole event doesn't involve deliberate intention.

Answer (score 2):

**[Accident](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accident)** addresses the reason (normally lack of intent) for some situation.

> It was an accident that I stubbed my toe.

**[Coincidence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coincidence)** addresses an observation of things that may be related, or may simply appear to be related (depending on how it is used).

> It was a coincidence that as I picked up the phone, I received a call.

Comment: So why haven't you close-voted rather than answered?

Comment: I have attempted to make a free-standing answer which would serve to help others with the same question in the future, per various guidelines at http://english.stackexchange.com/help/ - would voting the question down have been a better response? Please let me know, as I have only been participating for a month or so.

Comment: 'What do the standard definitions fail to explain?' is a suitable comment, but then providing standard definitions (which OP should have done) is not within the spirit of ELU.